# With WPF, scrolling down a ListView is fast, scrolling up is slow

Tags: wpf, listview, c#-3.0

I have a weird issue with my ListView. This ListView is linked to a DataSource containing a thousands items so it's pretty big.

My issue is that scrolling up is very slow... whereas scrolling down is ok. Any idea why?

Comment: What's the data source pointing to? An IEnumerable of something perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly an ObservableCollection.

Comment: I've got a similar problem here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345805/wpf-listview-on-portable-device-extremely-slow-scrolling/1345960#1345960 - I am using an ObservableCollection as well

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Recycling and DeferredScrolling

```
    <ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtulizationMode="Recycling" ...
    <ListBox ScrollView.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" ...
```