# Can WPF run without DirectX?

Tags: wpf, performance, directx

This might sound like a stupid question but ... will WPF stop running in absence of a DirectX/Direct3D capable graphics card/drivers or will it just run slower?

I know WPF is based on DirectX/Direct3D (even for simple controls) but I cannot find any reference on the topic which provides a good overview of borderline scenarios.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: As they say, http://despair.com/cluelessness.html. :P

Comment: that sounds about right ... ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

WPF has a dependency on the DirectX runtime. However, both DirectX and WPF have their own software fallback modes so that, in the absence of suitable graphics hardware and/or drivers, software rendering will be used instead. Some graphically intensive features will also be unavailable when software rendering. WPF allows you to check the [rendering tier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742196.aspx) that it's running under and tailor the UI to suit the current environment.

Comment: That link I provided and the subsequent topic (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970683.aspx) on optimisation are probably the best you'll find unfortunately.

Comment: Also, it's worth bearing in mind that the software-rendered performance can be painfully bad.

Comment: that is precisely why I am asking - I am running WPF on a portable device, drivers are not working and I am getting painful results (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345805/wpf-listview-on-portable-device-extremely-slow-scrolling). Also not too sure wrt how I can understand if software-rendering kicked-in or not.

Comment: Checking the tier that you're running under will give you a high-level idea of what performance you're likely to get. If you're in tier 0 then forget it;  tier 1 is usually ok if you don't do anything too crazy.

Comment: What is software rendering? Can any one describe briefly.Thanks