# Does WPF rely on Direct3D calls even for standard controls?

Tags: wpf, directx, direct3d

As a follow up tho [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1363308/can-wpf-run-without-directx/1363335#1363335) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149763/how-do-you-determine-if-wpf-is-using-hardware-or-software-rendering) other question, I am now trying to understand (out of curiosity) if WPF totally/mostly relies on Direct3D calls (and not 2D DirectDraw ones) even for standard controls, such as buttons or even the container window itself.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Presentation_Foundation) states:

> **All graphics, including desktop items like windows, are based on
>   Direct3D**

Is this true? Can someone expand and provide further resources on the subject?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this reference is really helpful - [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa663364.aspx)

> In fact, as described earlier, WPF
>   relies entirely on Direct3D for
>   rendering.

Comment: thanks - that link helped a lot (religious war going on in the office)

Answer (score 1):

It relies on d3d because you can composite even 2d "standard" controls onto a 3d surface if you wanted.

Check out this video which shows some of those capabilities:  http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/AdamKinney/WPF-35-SP1-Graphics-with-David-Teitlebaum/

Answer (score 0):

If you go into blend, select a button, and "edit a copy" of the button's template, you'll see the exact XAML that's used to make a WPF button look just like a "standard" (MFC?) button for the current windows theme. You can tweak this a tiny bit or a lot - and it will be rendered through the same pipeline as if you'd never touched the template.

So yes: even the "standard controls" are rendered via direct3d

Comment: +1 - seeing the underlying XAML makes it obvious that the controls are not from the 'standard' Win32/WinForms.

Answer (score -1):

Direct2D is deprecated. The interface still exists back from a previous version, but it is not being updated, and in current versions of DirectX you are supposed to use Direct3D for 2D work.

Comment: I don't think so, IE9 is using Direct2D.

Comment: Ahh, you are right, I was confusing Direct2D with DirectDraw.

Comment: @Pete I -1'd your answer to protect others from this confusion.